# Update modal with selected document

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm currently displaying a table with `Products` in my app, with one option to edit it using a `modal` window with Twitter Bootstrap.

I've managed to pass the `Product` to edit to my template using `Session` variables as follows, is this the proper way to achieve this or may I pass the object to the modal in a more direct way?

Thanks!

```
    Template.listProducts.events({
      'show.bs.modal #modal-edit-product': function (event) {
         Session.set("currentProduct", Products.findOne($(event.relatedTarget).data("productId")));
      },
    });

    Template.editProduct.helpers ({
      'product': function () {
        return Session.get("currentProduct");
      }
    });
```

Comment: looks good to me :-)

Comment: Also looks fine to me. Are you having any issues with it?

Comment: The problem goes when I try to edit an array inside that document, if I insert one item it wouldn't be displayed in the template unless I add it to the object returned by Session.get and then store it again using Session.set.. it seems non-reactive to me, any ideas?